# Using a date in an Excel function does not work when the date comes from another cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, date

I have the following problem: using a date as a condition in an MS Excel function works fine, as long as I write the date in the function code, such as `">1.1.2022"`.

But when I write the same date in a cell (e.g. `B1`) and (using the exactly same function) just refer to the cell, i.e. `"> B1"`, it doesn't work.
I get no error, just zero as the result (although it should be greater than zero). I have checked that the cell (here `B1`) has the format Date. Any ideas why this happens and what can be done?

Example: I want to calculate the sum of numbers in cells `C2:C25`, if the respective date in column `B` is above a specific date. This works:

```
=SUMIF(B2:B25,">1.1.2022",C2:C25)
```

But when I enter `1.1.2022` into cell `B1` and change the function to

```
=SUMIF(B2:B25,">B1",C2:C25)
```

the result is zero (although it should not be zero). `B1` is defined as a date in cell properties.

Answer (score 3):

You need to reference that cell, so putting `B1` in quotations doesn't work. Try this:

```
=SUMIF(B2:B25, ">"&B1, C2:C25)
```

Comment: This did it, thank you very much! And sorry for the delay in my response.

Comment: @user81805 if this resolved your problem, accept the answer by clicking on the checkmark beside the answer.

Comment: I'm sorry again, but did not notice this comment. Still learning to use the logic of these discussions... :) I would very much like to acknowledge the best answer, but I cannot see any place where a checkmark can be clicked. Where should it be and how should it look like?

Comment: @user81805 refer to this https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers there is a grayed out checkmark on the left side of the answers.